# Rails: parent build_association in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, callback, associations, parent-child

Developing a custom messaging system (yeah, I know...yet another one of those).

I have:

```
class Conversation << AR::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message << AR::Base
  belongs_to :conversation

  # this is what I want, create a conversation if one isn't assigned
  before_create :assign_to_conversation, :unless => :conversation

  def
    # but this won't save parent association
    build_conversation(:subject => subject, :starter => user)
  end
end
```

Basically, I want to be able track messages as part of a conversation. If a user sends a new msg, it should become part of a new conversation. If a msg is a reply to an existing convo, I just want to assign the message to that particular conversation.

In messages_controller I wish to just do

```
def create
  @message.save(params[:message]).
end
```

Without having to go with

```
def create
    transaction do
      c = Conversation.build(...)
      c.messages.build(params[:message])
      c.save
    end
end
```

I'm trying to keep my controllers simple and also conduct conversation and message creation as part of a single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Instead of before_create i know have

```
before_validation :assign_to_conversation, :on => :create, :unless => :conversation
```

Everything appears to work now. And all is wrapped up in a transaction.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Tried replacing `build_conversation` with `create_conversation` ?

Comment: Ah, wait. Your problem is the :unless => declaration. Try :unless => lambda { |x| x.conversation.present? }, or move the check for conversation presence into the method itself.

Comment: That did not work either. I suspect the validation on child record (message) runs before the before_create callback has a chance to run. Thus failing to create a message record without a valid conversation_id.

Comment: I traced the callback stack as it gets executed here. It makes sense now. I made it work by changing the
before_create to 
before_validation :on => :create.